# How to generate *.dict and *.idx file in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

Basically I have created a dictionary in python, say

```
dictionary = {'test': [1, 2, 3], 'other': [100]}
```

but I want to now write a program that would generate a dict file(say file1.dict) containing the dictionary and a idx file(say file2.idx) containing its inverted index posting.

Comment: Those aren't standard file formats (in this context, at least - `.idx` is subtitles for a movie and `.dict` translations for a virtual machine!) as far as I'm aware, what were you planning to put in them?

Comment: Please exemplify the desired output. The description is too vague.

Comment: Hey check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `.json` format for any objects you want to store. For that you can import the `json` library and then use `json.dump` to store the object and `json.load` to get it back.

If you want to mess with the format a bit you can use `json.dumps` which returns a string, then change whatever you want in that string and writing it to a file.

I would not suggest using the file formats you are describing because they are not standard as someone else mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

First to create a file use the following code-
Note: as .dict and .idx are not standard extensions I have used .txt

```
dict_file = open("sample.txt", "w+")
idx_file = open("sample.txt", "w+")
```

Now to write something in it use-

```
dict_file.write(#pass the dictionary in it)
idx_file.write(#pass the inverted index)
```

At last add the following code to close it-

```
dict_file.close()
idx_file.close()
```